# Perl - Iterating through an xml file and storing the data from specific tags

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I need to store specific data (file names) from an XML file into a hash using Perl.
I am iterating through the XML file line by line, but I am stuck on how to get the file names from `schooldata`'s `file` attribute.

The part of the XML that I am trying to access is like so:

```
<name number="5">
    <description>
        <schooldata file="/home/matt/.01"></schooldata>
    </description>
    <description>
        <schooldata file="/home/matt/.02"></schooldata>
    </description>
    <description>
        <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.3"></schooldata>
    </description>
    <description>
        <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.4"></schooldata>
    </description>
</name>
...
<name number="10">
...
</name>
```

Answer (score 2):

[XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig= new XML::Twig(
    twig_handlers => {
        schooldata => \&schooldata
    }
);

my %files;
$twig->parse(q(
<name number="5">
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/.01"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/.02"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.3"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.4"></schooldata>
          </description>
</name>
));


use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;
print Dumper(\%files);

sub schooldata {
    my ($twig, $data) = @_;
    $files{ $data->att('file') }++;
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '/home/matt/.01' => 1,
          '/home/matt/.02' => 1,
          '/home/matt/0.3' => 1,
          '/home/matt/0.4' => 1
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.014; 

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "xml.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($filename);

my %results;

for my $name ($doc->findnodes('/names/name')) {
    my $num = $name->getAttribute('number');

    for my $school ($name->findnodes('description/schooldata')) {
        push @{$results{$num}}, $school->getAttribute('file');
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper(\%results);


--output:--
$VAR1 = {
          '6' => [
                 '/home/betty/.01',
                 '/home/betty/.02',
                 '/home/betty/0.3',
                 '/home/betty/0.4'
               ],
          '5' => [
                 '/home/matt/.01',
                 '/home/matt/.02',
                 '/home/matt/0.3',
                 '/home/matt/0.4'
               ]
        };
```

xml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<names>
<name number="5">
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/.01"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/.02"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.3"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/matt/0.4"></schooldata>
          </description>
</name>

<name number="6">
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/betty/.01"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/betty/.02"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/betty/0.3"></schooldata>
          </description>
          <description>
                      <schooldata file="/home/betty/0.4"></schooldata>
          </description>
</name>
</names>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$line = '<schooldata file="/home/matt/.01"></schooldata>';
print $1 if ($line =~ /schooldata file="([^"]+)"/);
```